# HTML5 <!DOCTYPE html> CSS

Tags: html5

Por que al usuar DOCTYPE html los css del div no formatea la altura (height)?

archivo css

```css
.cont{
  height:80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      
   <body>
     <div class='cont'></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si quieres que tu `div` tenga el 80% de la altura de la ventana puedes ocupar `height: 80vh` en vez de `height: 80%;`.

Comment: Piensa un poco, estás diciendo que el div es el 80% del body, pero es que el body está vacío, no tiene nada, por tanto ¿Cúal es el 80% de 0? Pues 0. Por eso no hace lo que quieres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No lo hagas así, Doctype elimina la declaración de altura como porcentaje en CSS

```
html, body {
height: 100%;}
```

Agregar un DOCTYPE reemplaza el modo peculiar al modo estándar. En el modo estándar, los elementos html y body no tienen por defecto el 100 % del tamaño de la ventana gráfica (ventana del navegador); en cambio, son tan grandes como deben ser para contener a sus hijos.

Comment: Gracias la respuestas me ayudo, consegui este material que explica y coincide con lo que afirmas. https://foroayuda.es/por-que-la-altura-funciona-al-100-cuando-se-elimina-doctype/